# problems while implementing android GCM demo

Tags: android, ant, google-cloud-messaging

I put in reference this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

in Using App Engine for Java number 4
I am supposed to run this on a cmd inside the samples/gcm-demo-appengine directory :ant -Dsdk.dir=/opt/google/appengine-java-sdk runserver -Dserver.host=192.168.1.10

I replace the "192.168.1.10" with "127.0.0.1" which is my locolhost.

after executing this command I got:

BUILD FAILED

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-ap
pengine\build.xml:27: Cannot find C:\opt\google\appengine-java-sdk\config\user\a
nt-macros.xml imported from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-appengine\build.xml
```

can you tell me what the problem?

Comment: In `build.xml`, there is a variable called `sdk.dir`. Make sure that points to the correct location.

Comment: where it should point to ? @SherifelKhatib

Comment: android-sdk, wherever you installed it

Comment: Hi Karim have you solved this problem , because I am also facing the same please reply ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following link:

[[https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Java]](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Java%5d)

And download appengine-java-sdk-1.9.3.zip

So than extract it where you want and use the following path for example:

```
C:\programs\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.3
```

so you will use :

```
ant -Dsdk.dir=C:\programs\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.3 runserver -Dserver.host=1.1.1.1
```

where you have to replace 1.1.1.1 with your server's ip